# ASP.NET Core Authorization Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-middleware

What I want to do is write some ASP.NET Core middleware to authorize a user before he can see the content of a view.

I'm using the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/) package for my sessions.

The code of the middleware:

```
// simplified code that should check if the Session is valid
if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("xyz") == null)
{
    //Return to Login View;
}
// else (when the session is valid) return to the view that the user wants to view.
```

What I don't understand:

- How I can redirect the user to another page through the middleware.
- How to use the middleware properly in my project
- If middleware is the right approach for such a task
- Or how to use the sessions in the middleware. It does not work the way I use them in the controller.

[Image of the implementation of the middleware in my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciL8O.png)

Answer (score 0):

> How I can redirect the user to another page through the middleware.
>
> how to use the middleware properly in my project

If you want to check the session and redirect user under some condition,
You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) realted and try with a middleware as below in Program.cs

```
.......
app.UseRouting()
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Session.TryGetValue("key",out var val))
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("targeturi");
    }
    else
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
});
......
```

> If middleware is the right approach for such a task

There're  already Auth Service in asp.net core ,you could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and choose  one

> or how to use the sessions in the middleware. It does not work the way
> I use them in the controller.

Your picture indicated you were tring with Filter(TypeFilterAttribute),not middleware ,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#typefilterattribute) realted

If you want to try with Authorization Filter,you could try to create a filter like:

```
public class SomeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("key",out var val))
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectResult("Index");
            }
        }
    }
```

apply the filter:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(SomeFilter))]
```